# Sync between two Amazon RDS MySQL databases on a daily basis

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have one existing Amazon RDS MySQL database. But due to some reason now I have created a new RDS database (using existing RDS snapshot) with same structure along some additional columns in a table.

Now I want to copy newly entered data from existing RDS database to new RDS database automatically on daily basis.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Is the copy a perimate read replica (https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/) or is this some test environment that you are going to be modifying data on and requiring a full re-sync?

Comment: data is coming only in few tables of old rds, so I want to sync new rds to newly entered data once a day.